# Recover bitcoins?

Tags: bitcoin-core, client, multibit-hd

I was using MultiBit HD and it was working fine till somehow my kaspers key start to delete it. Then i installed Bitcoin Core without knowing anything about it. and it started to downloading bitcoin blockchain but before it finish i created a payment receive address and put it in my bitpay account. And they sent the payment

I stop downloading bitcoin blockchain because its really big. Is there any chance i can get my bitcoins in another wallet? I have the privet keys from Bitcoin Core

Answer (score 1):

you can try and use Electrum wallet. Here is a guide on how to transfer coins from Bitcoin core to Electrum

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transferring_coins_from_Bitcoin-Qt_to_Electrum

Comment: i did try this nothing happened

Comment: Are you able to dump private key? This alone should be enough to gain control over the address with any wallet software that has sweeping.

Comment: Yes did it.when i check the transaction in https://blockchain.info it shows with red arrow. I'm not sure what this mean

Comment: Ye, I'm not sure about the blockchain.info red arrow. Nevertheless, check bitpay transactions, and see if you really sent funds correctly. If yes, use this private key (the one dumped by bitcoin core) and import it to some wallet application (most of them have options to import private keys).

Comment: Well its showing its transfered but i don't see the coins in my wallet

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as you have the private key you have control over the bitcoins that are at the address corresponding to the private key.

I would suggest you generate a address in the wallet you now want to use. 
Some websites make it easy to make bitcoin transactions (e.g., http://bitclient.org) -but you must look around to see that the website you use is not a scam of course.

Comment: Ok but how do i recover the coins?